# Facebook app functionality

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to create a facebook app for my web app. I would like it to post on a user's behalf every time the user creates a new album on my site. I am hoping to make it act like Pinterest whereas users in my news feed tend to have posts saying "Emily Sue pinned to 2 boards on Pinterest". Is this automatically generated or does the Pinterest user have to hit the Facebook "share" button on Pinterest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) app. Facebook has a [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) which will guide you trough the key steps.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has the publish permissions you can automatically post on his wall.